# Age problems in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I just want to know how we translate age problems where a variable in unknown into a **Python program**. Example:

Father is four times the age of his daughter. If after 5 years, he would be threee times of daughter’s age, then further after 5 years, how many times he would be of his daughter’s age?

Without defining age of the daughter, how can we determine the current ages of father and daughter to find the ratio?

**Does this problem even translate to a Python program?** (I've just begun learning it due to lockdown and wanted to see if it was possible). Thanks for any helpful answers.

Comment: This basically is a mathematics question. You can always create logic and then implement it in any programming language. Give it a shot.

Comment: never used it, but there is a library called [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) that handles mathematical computations.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Seems simpler to do the algebra by hand.  Is it an exercise in python, or are you asking because you want to solve other algebra problems with python?

Comment: Hey Nathan! I'm just trying juggle the math with the code, trying to learn both as I'm from tourism industry and this is all new to me. When I had a thought that it would be great if we could automate math equations with code but it turns out it's not that simple. Although, if we could program something that can read and identify math symbols, that would be more robust. But, I think I have miles to go before I can even come close to do that. But, I'm learning and people have been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is fair to give you a hint on how a python script could be written to solve it.  If you replace all the `?` in the code below with the correct `int` values then you'll have a python program that solves this problem:

```
for daughter in range(100):
    father = ? * daughter
    if (father + ?) / (daughter + ?) == ?:
        break

ratio_10y = (father + ?) / (daughter + ?)
```

[play around with it in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=for%20daughter%20in%20range%28100%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20father%20%3D%20%3F%20*%20daughter%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28father%20%2B%20%3F%29%20/%20%28daughter%20%2B%20%3F%29%20%3D%3D%20%3F%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20break%0Aratio_10y%20%3D%20%28father%20%2B%20%3F%29%20/%20%28daughter%20%2B%20%3F%29&cumulative=true&heapPrimitives=false&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: I solved it. It was more of a mathematical question than a python one. I apologise. yincrease = int(input ("How many times old is father (y): ")) ftime = int(input ("How many years have passed (k): ")) newincrease = int(input("How many time old is the father now(z): ")) answerdaughter = (int(ftime)*int(newincrease)-int(ftime))/(int(yincrease)-int(newincrease)) print (answerdaughter)....I know it isn't the mostly glorious of codes but I used to work in tourism industry and just started to learn the code. Appreciate the helpful comments.

Comment: I think I bit more than I can chew here. I thought there could be a universal solution to a problems like these using code, I was so wrong. Each problem would require a new set of formula. Could we have a universally acceptable code for such problems? Let's say if I'm asked a question like "A man said to his son, "I was one-third of your present age when you were born". If the present age of the man is 48 years, find the present age of the son." the above model fails. Can there be one single algorithm to solve both these questions and questions of such nature?

Comment: That question is solvable in python, but I believe it requires a completely different algorithm because the input parameters are different.  That being said, you could always write a function that checks what inputs are available and then employs the correct algorithm for the provided inputs or returns an error message if there are not enough inputs required to solve it.